# So I am having problems reading (loading into array) this file?

Tags: java, arrays, text, load

So I am having problems reading (loading into array) this file

For this project, download the text file weblog.txt 
http://www.santarosa.edu/~lmeade/weblog.txt

Note: To download this file, right click on the link and select SAVE AS.

I saved in on my desktop

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class project4 {

    static Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

    public static final String INPUT_FILENAME="weblog.txt";

    public static final String OUTPUT_FILENAME="sorted_weblog.txt";

    public static final int MAX=2990;

    public static String[] fileContent=new String[MAX];

    public static int count=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        readFile();
        sortFileContent();
        writeFile();
    }

    public static void readFile() {
        try {
            File f= new File(INPUT_FILENAME);
            Scanner br = new Scanner(f);
            String sCurrentLine;
            while (br.hasNext()) {
                 sCurrentLine = br.nextLine();
                 fileContent[count++]=sCurrentLine;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not Found");
        }
    }

    private static void sortFileContent() {
        Arrays.sort(fileContent);
    }

    private static void writeFile() {
        PrintWriter out;
        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(new File(OUTPUT_FILENAME));
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                out.println(fileContent[i]);
            }
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not Found");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: if the webblog.txt isn't in the same Directory and your project you need to put the full path. Also, throw your stack trace and specific problem in there to help us help you.

Comment: Fixed code formatting for better readability.